# Pipes paginado ordenar Angular 2+

Tags: angular

Estoy haciendo una tabla que tenga la funcionalidad de paginado y que se pueda ordenar.

```
<tbody>
  <tr class="table-font" *ngFor="let item of items 
     | slice: (page - 1) * pageSize:page * pageSize | orderBy: order">
          <td>
            <p>{{ item.producto }}</p>
          </td>
```

Tengo el pipe de ordenar, y el pipe de paginar.Ambas de diferentes librerias.
El tema es que quiero que primero se ordene y después se pagine, ya que de no ser asi solo me ordena el contenido del paginado mas no del todo contenido que alimenta la tabla.
No se como factorearlo para que funcione.

Comment: Para referencia futura, una forma rápida que se me ocurre de ordenar ambas es creando tu propio pipe que aplique las otras pipes que quieres usar en el orden correcto.

Answer (score 0):

Suponiendo que traes todos los datos en una consulta debería bastar con modificar el orden de los pipes que estas usando:

```
<tr class="table-font" *ngFor="let item of items | orderBy: order
     | slice: (page - 1) * pageSize:page * pageSize" >
```

Comment: Si, es lo primero que probe. Al final lo termine usando otra libreria. Por mas que intente factorizar para que funcione no obtuve un buen resultado.